# How to apply business rules to a WCF data service in a generic way, backed up by EF6

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, web-services, wcf-data-services

I have this requirement to create a REST API to manipulate a database. I decided on WCF Data Services v5.6 because i don't want to rewrite the wheel and i think that way is becoming the standard.

BUT, i need to apply business rules to the objects. All entities involved derive from a base class that has control fields like IsDeleted and so that need checking for example, against a select/GET.

My design has 4 projects:

- **DomainModel:** Contains only the POCO entities (made by separating the Model.tt  into a new project
- **DataAccessLayer:** Contains the Context.tt that generates the **EventsDomainModel** context class
- **BusinessLayer:** Contains a custom DbContext that does the validation, more on this in a moment
- **RestApi:** The website and the services.

Currently, this is the validation i have:

```
public class GenericBusinessValidator<T>:DbContext where T: class, IBaseEntity
    {
        private DbContext _ctx;
        private DbSet<T> _set;
        /// <summary>
        /// Standard constructor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context">The DbContext object</param>
        public GenericBusinessValidator(DbContext context)
        {
            _ctx = context;
            _set = _ctx.Set<T>();

        }

        public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
        {
            return _set.Where(x => x.IsActive == true);
        } 
    }
```

and the code needed to make the service work (Events.svc) is the standard

```
 public class Events : EntityFrameworkDataService<EventsDomainModel>
    {
        // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
        public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
        {
            // TODO: set rules to indicate which entity sets and service operations are visible, updatable, etc.
            // Examples:
            config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
            config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.All);
            config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
        }
    }
```

Now, what i am trying to achieve is to REPLACE the  EventsDomainModel class wich is the vanilla DbContext -derived class from the second piece of code with the first, that does the validation but i dont know how;

The way i understand, my validator deals with a specific DbSet inside a given DbContext; the code from the WCF service needs a specific dbContext.

So,  how can i validate all DbSets without particularizing my class, ie, avoid making

```
public class GenericBusinessValidator<T>:DbContext where T: class, IBaseEntity
    {
        private DbContext _ctx;
        private DbSet<T> _set;
        /// <summary>
        /// Standard constructor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context">The DbContext object</param>
        public GenericBusinessValidator(DbContext context)
        {
            _ctx = context;
            _set = _ctx.Set<T>();

        }

        private DbSet<Venue> Venues;
        private DbSet<EventCategory> Categories;
        ...
        ...
        ...
```

**BASICALLY, what i'm trying to accomplish is**

make sure that a call like
http://localhost/Events.svc/EventCategories?$format=application/json

returns me all EventCategories **that have isActive=true** (applied generically) WITHOUT resorting to ServiceOperations and thus avoiding defeating the purpose of using REST

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, what i needed were QueryInterceptors and ChangeInterceptors

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744842(v=vs.110).aspx